# how fetch events from my sql - FULL Calendar

Tags: php, mysql

I receive null value in the result:title, but in the DB there's a value in location_end

```
<?php 
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host;dbname', 'user', 'pass');

    $result = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM schedule");
        $result->execute();
        $event_array = array();
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        while ($record = $result->fetch()) {
            $event_array[] = array(
                'id' => $record['id'],
                'title' => $record['location_end'],
                'start' => $record['start_time'],
                'end' => $record['end_time'],
            );
        } 
    echo json_encode($event_array);


  events: {
            url: 'http://localhost/FleetManagement/getEvents.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(){
                alert('Get Events Successfull!!');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        }
```

Result: the title should have value but i receive null

```
  result [{"id":"1","title":null,"start":"2016-01-14 00:15:00","end":"2016-01-14 01:00:00"},{"id":"2","title":null,"start":"2016-01-20 23:45:00","end":"2016-01-20 23:45:00"},{"id":"3","title":null,"start":"2016-01-14 23:45:00","end":"2016-01-14 23:45:00"},{"id":"4","title":null,"start":"2016-01-14 23:45:00","end":"2016-01-14 23:45:00"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> in the result-title, I receive null values

You're trying to use the `location_end` field, but that column is not in your SQL select;

```
SELECT id, start_time, end_time, status, approval_status FROM schedule
```

You need to add that column to your SQL;

```
SELECT id, location_end, start_time, end_time, status, approval_status FROM schedule
```

Comment: Sorry its not latest source code, I edited my query! same result null value in the title

Answer (score 0):

Try to print `$event_array` before json_encode.
It seems to me that 'location_end' is containing some non-utf8 encoding characters.

Comment: How to remove the non-utf8 encoding characters?

Comment: There are many ways: Like set character set of your table utf8.  At the time of data insert set "SET CHARACTER SET utf8". when insert data you can use "utf_encode" & when show data in front end use "utf_decode"